"An associated PostScript font (required by Matplotlib) could not be found for TeX font 'zptmcm7y' in
An associated PostScript font (required by Matplotlib) could not 
be found for TeX font 'zptmcm7y' in 
'C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map'; 
this problem can often be solved by installing a suitable 
PostScript font package in your TeX package manager

so that's the whole error message. I am not sure as to how that occurred because before, it's a different error message (exactly like this, just with different font)
The postscript font in question has a file here somewhere but it is not recognized in the pdftex.map I guess.
I need help resolving this. Thank you in advance.

Welcome! What do you mean 'has a file here somewhere'? On my system, there is no zptmcm7y.pfb, for example, but zpfmcm7y.vf. That's a virtual font and not expected to be listed in the .map files. Is this error produced by a .tex document? Can you provide an example to reproduce the error? Also, can you compile other .tex documens? Because I don't think the issue here is the same as the one you linked.

Hi! I also don't have 'zptmcm7y.pfb' but what I do have is 'zptmcm7y.htf' 'zptmcm7y.tfm' as well as 'zptmcm7y.vf' . Am I supposed to have the .pfb file too?
it's an error in a python script that somebody else wrote and I'm just editing stuff in it. That's where the error occurred. I am not really sure how I can provide an example for the error to be reproduced. Could you help me with the specifics
Oh that one issue I linked is the one similar to the other error I got that stumped me. This one is different though

So htf is for use with tex4ht for producing html from tex source. No, you wouldn't usually have a pfb. Rather, the vf will point to real fonts. So, ultimately, you have to have pfb(s) but they will have different names. I don't know what matplotlib does, but it shouldn't be looking in the map files for a virtual font. What tex does is read the virtual font and follow the redirections to pick characters from other (real) fonts. Virtual fonts are a way of combining characters from different fonts (usually) into a single tex font. Only the real fonts get map lines.

From the documentation: ' These virtual fonts are made up
basically from Times Italic, with the missing math symbols coming from CM,
RSFS (for \mathcal) and Adobe Symbol.' (psnfss2e.pdf page 6)

how do I fix this issue?

I can't answer that because I don't know what code is producing the issue. I assume you have a .tex file somewhere (perhaps generated by the script) which causes pdfTeX to generate an error which results in that message, but you haven't shared the error message, the log file or the code which produces it. since I've never used matplotlib, I'm not in a position to guess.

this is the code that gets jammed by the error above  https://onlinegdb.com/4sGS8_OGh
let me know which part is important that's not included in the linked so I'll append it

I don't know python and I don't know what that code ends up doing in context (and I don't usually follow external links) but it looks unproblematic to me. The problem is whatever is asking that code for a virtual font as if it was an actual font. Is this actually being compiled by TeX? because I  think this question is just off-topic and doesn't have anything to do with TeX really at all. You wouldn't normally need a python script to produce either dvi or pdf - you don't need python at all and windows users rarely have it. so whatever this is, it doesn't look like tex to me?
